# Error with pip install -r requirements.txt

Tags: python, debugging, build, pip, anaconda3

I'm following the setup on https://github.com/ilaria-manco/word2wave but when I enter the command `pip install -r requirements.txt` I get all these errors.

What should I do to fix these errors?

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Computer\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Computer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zlefje0x\\numba_6d911659eda14b0f8d066edc375b6f3d\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Computer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zlefje0x\\numba_6d911659eda14b0f8d066edc375b6f3d\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-mnv7lq0f'
       cwd: C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zlefje0x\numba_6d911659eda14b0f8d066edc375b6f3d\

  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  building 'numba._dynfunc' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for numba
  Running setup.py clean for numba
  Building wheel for llvmlite (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Computer\anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Computer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zlefje0x\\llvmlite_4c2699e7f4e54dcb91e5fdbb477099bf\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Computer\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-zlefje0x\\llvmlite_4c2699e7f4e54dcb91e5fdbb477099bf\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-7mb2w19u'
       cwd: C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zlefje0x\llvmlite_4c2699e7f4e54dcb91e5fdbb477099bf\
  Complete output (24 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  C:\Users\Computer\anaconda3\python.exe C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zlefje0x\llvmlite_4c2699e7f4e54dcb91e5fdbb477099bf\ffi\build.py
  Trying generator 'Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zlefje0x\llvmlite_4c2699e7f4e54dcb91e5fdbb477099bf\ffi\build.py", line 192, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zlefje0x\llvmlite_4c2699e7f4e54dcb91e5fdbb477099bf\ffi\build.py", line 180, in main
      main_win32()
    File "C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zlefje0x\llvmlite_4c2699e7f4e54dcb91e5fdbb477099bf\ffi\build.py", line 89, in main_win32
      generator = find_win32_generator()
    File "C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zlefje0x\llvmlite_4c2699e7f4e54dcb91e5fdbb477099bf\ffi\build.py", line 77, in find_win32_generator
      try_cmake(cmake_dir, build_dir, generator)
    File "C:\Users\Computer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zlefje0x\llvmlite_4c2699e7f4e54dcb91e5fdbb477099bf\ffi\build.py", line 28, in try_cmake
      subprocess.check_call(['cmake', '-G', generator, cmake_dir])
    File "C:\Users\Computer\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 368, in check_call
      retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Computer\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 349, in call
      with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
    File "C:\Users\Computer\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
      self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    File "C:\Users\Computer\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
      hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
  error: command 'C:\\Users\\Computer\\anaconda3\\python.exe' failed with exit code 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for llvmlite
  Running setup.py clean for llvmlite
Failed to build numba llvmlite
Installing collected packages: llvmlite, numba, torch, resampy, audioread, torchaudio, pescador, librosa
  Attempting uninstall: llvmlite
    Found existing installation: llvmlite 0.37.0
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'llvmlite'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you read each line of the error message?

Did you install Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater?

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Make sure `pip --version` is for the Python version you're using for your project.

Comment: I installed Visual Studio and now I get these errors: ```ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1``` ```ERROR: Failed building wheel for llvmlite``` ```ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'llvmlite'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.```

Comment: I'm not a Windows user, but I would guess that you installed `llvmlite` via distutils and now are trying to install a different version of it using `pip`. Perhaps try uninstalling `llvmlite` with distutils, then running `pip` again?

Comment: In general, try to stick to one system for managing your packages and if you do run into these sorts of errors, uninstall **everything**, and then reinstall using the instructions provided.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/, click on download build tools, Check ✓ C++ build tools when installing.